# Chrome - UI frozen but script running in extension mode

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, popup, freeze

I am stuck on this for a long time and was wondering if anyone has any clue on what might be happening.

I am using Chrome 25.0.1364.152 on a Mac OS Lion 10.7.4.

The page basically updates forex quotes from a server and
displays the updated quotes. It fires off the update call
every second.

Though it works without any issues, when running as a Chrome browser
action popup extension, the UI just freezes at a random point,
mostly just after the popup opens up. However, I can monitor
from my server that the page is still sending the update requests,
which means the script is running.

There are no errors on the console, and the page and its elements
can be inspected without any problems. Everything seems to be
working, but the UI wont update ( it also does not accept
input like mouse clicks ).

I have tried clearing the Chrome cache, I have also deleted the
Chrome profile, nothing helps.